# Invalid data found when processing input | ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concat multiple videos with ffmpeg, im using a text file as input but im getting "Files.txt: Invalid data found when processing input".

My command:

```
ffmpeg -i Files.txt -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=25,format=yuv420p,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[1:v]fps=25,format=yuv420p,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[1:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

My text file:

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
```

Comment: did you find the reason ?@GoekhanDev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Only the concat demuxer accepts a text file list

Either use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt output.mp4
```

Or list the inputs normally and use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=25,format=yuv420p,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[1:v]fps=25,format=yuv420p,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[1:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

You can't use a text file listing inputs unless you use the concat demuxer as shown above, or if you use some capability in your shell to interpret the list as inputs. `ffmpeg` has no such feature.

Comment: Im using filter complex for a reason, concat makes no sense for my usecase. The second option works but im trying to do it with a text file.

Comment: @VRX This answer directly answers the question "Invalid data found when processing input", but it now seems the actual question is "how can I use a file list as input with ffmpeg (but not for concat demuxer)"?

Comment: Not it's not answering the question since it's very obvious what im trying to do. Im using filter complex, because every video that Im trying to merge is not the same format. If I would've use "concat" the video output is corrupted. The solution that im looking for is avoid the issue I am getting. Not a diffrent way to use a text file as input since there is no other way.

Comment: @VRX You can't use a text file as an input unless: A) you are using the concat demuxer, or B) you use some capability of your shell. It's not a feature in ffmpeg.

Comment: Well, that would be a answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: is there a way to specify more than 2 inputs?

Comment: @VRX `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=25,format=yuv420p,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[1:v]fps=25,format=yuv420p,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[1:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that you have your file is encoded in a **non UTF-8** encoding. Try to save the file in **UTF-8** encoding.

Comment: Sadly, that's not the issue.

Comment: ohhh okay. can you try to concat the files without the list file?

Comment: Im using filter complex because the videos don't have the same format. If I would use concat the video output would be corrupted.